# “Null” error with some tables on same page with R readHTMLTable

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape tables data on the following page
[HKJC LINK](http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/Results/english/Local/20180715/ST/6)

I can read table 2 and 3, but the table 1 returned "NULL", I checked source codes which are containing data [(see the picture)](https://upload.cc/i1/2018/08/28/vCrsVu.png)

```
    library(XML)
    url = "http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/Results/english/Local/20180715/ST/6"
    sample=readHTMLTable(url,which=2,encoding = "UTF-8")
    head(sample,1)
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(XML)

scrapescrape <- function(x) {

  link <- paste0("http://www.racingpost.com/horses/horse_home.sd?horse_id=",x)

    tryCatch(readHTMLTable(link, which=2), error=function(e){NA})

  }
}

ids <- c(896119, 766254, 790946, 556341,  62736, 660506, 486791, 580134, 0011, 580134)

lst <- lapply(ids, scrapescrape)

str(lst)
```